# Trying to understand Ruby arrays

Tags: ruby

```
array = [:peanut, :butter, :and, :jelly]
```

Why does `array[4,0]` return `[]` and `array[5,0]` returns `nil`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [`Array#[] documentation`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D):

> an empty array is returned when the starting index for an element
>   range is at the end of the array.
>
> Returns nil if the index (or starting index) are out of range.

```
a = [ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" ]
a[2] +  a[0] + a[1]    #=> "cab"
a[6]                   #=> nil
a[1, 2]                #=> [ "b", "c" ]
a[1..3]                #=> [ "b", "c", "d" ]
a[4..7]                #=> [ "e" ]
a[6..10]               #=> nil
a[-3, 3]               #=> [ "c", "d", "e" ]
# special cases
a[5]                   #=> nil
a[6, 1]                #=> nil
a[5, 1]                #=> []
a[5..10]               #=> []
```